# REST API SERVICE FOR COLLECTING FORM DATA in JAVA

Tags: rest, api

im planning to develop a webapplication using java and HTML implementing as REST Services and confused how ot start with what technologies..
As a First step my first requirement is just creating a login HTML page and create REST SERVICE for LOGIN which validates the user by connecting to Database and generates a session and next page say shopping page.

Please suggest the Java jars,ide, etc to start.

Comment: The title and description are conflict together.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, your problem is very complex.
To make a website such as shopping page, you can write code with REST services or no need.

If REST Services  is used, you must build and setup 2 system/application: web app & server app. (front-end & back-end). With any system/app, you need  technologies its own.

To done, you must know many knowledges such as: 
API, Rooter, OOP, MVC, how to connect DB,...
There are many IDE such as Eclipse,... or only need a Editor with a few plugin.

Comment: HI bui,  FYI,im planing to build a shopping site as u said with front end being developed by HTML ,JavaScript and Backend With REST Services(this is where im stuck). im aware of builiding with servlets/jsp but i want to construct REST services,which my front end should connect .i just want build loign,join,cart,payment etc some modules as REST Services. i want to use Java as my technology.